# How to access the asp control using $(this) within the setTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a list of HTML controls and I need to bind a listener for the `keyup` event to each of these. Once that is triggered, some other actions should subsequently be kicked off after a time delay. I'm using `setTimeout` for that.

```
$(".TextBoxClass").each(function () {
  $(this).keyup(function () {
    alert("Id = " + $(this));    
    setTimeout(function () { 
       alert("current Id = " + $(this))
    }, 50);
  })
})
```

The first `alert` message shows the correct `id` of the control which triggers the `keyup` event. The second `alert` within the `setTimeout` says `current id = [object][object]`.

How can I access the control within the `setTimeout` callback function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div id="controls">
    <input class="TextBoxClass" type="text" value="1" id="id-1">
    <input class="TextBoxClass" type="text" value="2" id="id-2">
    <input class="TextBoxClass" type="text" value="3" id="id-3">
    <input class="TextBoxClass" type="text" value="4" id="id-4">
    <input class="TextBoxClass" type="text" value="5" id="id-5">
  </div>


$('#controls').on('keyup', '.TextBoxClass', function () {
  var $this = $(this);

  setTimeout(function(){ 
    // alert("current value = " + $this.val()); 
    alert("current element id = " + $this.attr('id')); 
  }, 50);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/yisore/1/

http://jsbin.com/yisore/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

'this' identifier goes out of scope inside setTimeout method.Try to store the object reference in a variable and use inside the setTimeout method like in this example...

```
$(".TextBoxClass").each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);

    $(this).keyup(function () {
        alert("Id = "+ obj); 
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            alert("current Id = " + obj)}, 50);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use event object as you are handling event function here.

```
$(".TextBoxClass").each(function () {
    $(this).keyup(function (e) {
        alert(e.target);
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(e.target);
        }, 50);
    });
});
```

Have a look at the documentation on the [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `this` keyword depends on your function scope. In the outer function scope, `this` is the DOM element which triggered the event. In your `setTimeout` scope, it's the global `window` object. Store a reference to your DOM element in the outer function scope, and use that when alerting the ID later on:

```
$(".TextBoxClass").keyup(function () {
    var self = this;
    alert("Id = " + self.id);
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert("current Id = " + self.id)
    },50);
});
```

Also, there's no reason to do any iteration. [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) can bind to all elements at once.